# Concentration of holes diffusion problem

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, definite-integrals

Suppose we have this problem:Let $C(x,t)$ be the concentration of holes in a PN crystal
[image]

Let us have 2 boundary conditions $C(0,t)=1$ and $C(1,t)=0$ and also $C(x,0)=e^{-x}(x-1)^{2}$

I am using the diffusion equation $\frac{d^{2}C}{dx^{2}} = \frac{dC}{dt}$.Because 1 boundary condition isnt zero lets solve the problem as if it were 0.So we would get this set of equations
[image]

Now lets solve the problem when all the boundary conditions are 0 and then we will add 1 linear term of a steady state condition.By seperation of variables of $C(x,t)$ we end up with this solution for the problem when all boundary conditions are 0:

$C(x,t) = \sum_{0}^{\infty}Bnsin(n\pi x)e^{-(n\pi)^{2}t}$ with Bn being equal to $2\int_{0}^{1}e^{-x}(x-1)^{2}sin(n\pi x)dx$

How do I solve the last integral?

Comment: Wolfram-Alpha gives $$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x}(x-1)^2\sin(n\pi x)dx = \frac{\pi n (\pi^4n^4-4\pi^2n^2+3)}{(\pi^2n^2+1)^3}$$ It likely solves it by doing integration by parts on the complex integral $\int_0^{\infty} e^{zx}(x-1)^2dx$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: For example by integration by parts we can get $\int_0^b xe^{zx}dx$ and then we can get $\int_0^b x^2e^{zx}dx$. When the real part of $z$ is negative, which it is, we can take $b\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: @Michael I have a small typo I will edit

Comment: Done editting..

Comment: It appears you changed $\int_0^{\infty}$ to $\int_0^1$. You can solve it by the same integration by parts, Wolfram-alpha gives a slightly more complicated answer.

Comment: I cannot insert any of the Wolfram links for the problem I entered (as I used to be able to do) since this comment section breaks the links in half and results in a non-clickable thing. The website I am using is: https://www.wolframalpha.com/

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following trick:
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}e^{-x}(x-1)^{2}\sin(n\pi x)dx&=\Im\left(\int_{0}^{1}e^{-x+in\pi x}(x-1)^{2}dx\right) \\
&=\Im\left(\left(-\frac{d}{dt}-1\right)^2\int_{0}^{1}e^{-tx+in\pi x}dx\right)_{t=1} \\
&=\Im\left(\left(\frac{d}{dt}+1\right)^2\frac{e^{-tx+in\pi x}}{-t+in\pi}\bigg|_0^1\right)_{t=1} \\
&=\Im\left(\left(\frac{d}{dt}+1\right)^2\frac{(-1)^ne^{-t}-1}{-t+in\pi}\right)_{t=1} \\
&=-n\pi\left(\frac{d}{dt}+1\right)^2\frac{(-1)^ne^{-t}-1}{t^2+n^2\pi^2}\bigg|_{t=1}.
\end{align}
I leave the last step to you.